# python list value make a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to make my list value as list.

example :

```
abc = [1,2,3,4]
```

result :

```
abc = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

I found that `numpy` library is needed. however I don't know how to change that. Who know the solution?

Comment: `[[v] for v in abc]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy, you can add a new axis:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(abc)[:, np.newaxis]
Out: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that the answer is best.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you need numpy. A list comprehension should do.

```
abc = [[x] for x in abc]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:-

```
abc = map(lambda x:[x], abc)
```

Answer (score 2):

A non `list comprehension` or `lambda function` version would be

```
abc = [1,2,3]
arr = []

for x in abc:
    arr.append([x])

print arr
```

I believe this is more intuitive for beginners but less 'pythonic'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[x] for x in abc])
```